How to differentiate between repeated fields in a pdf using PyMuPDF
I have a pdf where there are some fields like this:
( ) I do not have tax residency outside Brazil.

Today I can fill this type with an X using PyMuPDF, but now a case has arisen where there is a repetition of this field on another page, how can I fill these repetitions with different values
Today my code looks like this:
pdf = fitz.open(document)

for page_num in range(len(pdf)):
    page = pdf.load_page(page_num)
    text = pagina.get_text("text")

    areas = page.search_for("( ) I do not have tax residency outside Brazil.")

    for area in areas:
        page.insert_text((area.x0 + 1.7, area.y0 + 9.5), "X", fontsize=9, color=(0, 0, 0))

pdf.save(f"{local_download}\\{file_name_to_save}")
pdf.close()

I tried a few ways to solve it but they had no effect.
I'll leave an example pdf, in it there are 2 pages and on each page there is the field informed: Test File

What keeps you from writing a different content in other pages than number 1?

This example puts a different character inside the brackets (), depending on page number.
I am not sure whether I understood your problem ...
import pymupdf as fitz
import string

alfabet = string.ascii_uppercase  # enough for 26 pages ...

doc = fitz.open("test.pdf")

for page in doc:
    areas = page.search_for("( ) I do not have tax residency outside Brazil.")
    text = alfabet[page.number]
    for area in areas:
        page.insert_text(area.tl + (2.3, 10.5), text, fontname="hebo", fontsize=9)

doc.ez_save(doc.name + "-marked.pdf")
doc.close()

Page 2 looks like this:


Thanks friend, but I decided to split the pdf page by page and work on the pages, as soon as the filling work is done I join the pages and create a final document with the fields filled in.

After several attempts to solve this problem I decided to split the pdf file into pages and work page by page, so I got the expected result.
I've come up with a few methods for this:
def split_pdf(pdf_file):
    document = fitz.open(pdf_file)

    for num_page in range(len(document)):
        new_page = fitz.open()
        new_page.insert_pdf(document, from_page=num_page, to_page=num_page)
        new_page.save(f"{num_page}.pdf")
        new_page.close()

def join_pages(folder, output_file):
    single_pdf = fitz.open()

    pdf_files = sorted([os.path.join(folder, f) for f in os.listdir(folder) if f.endswith('.pdf')])

    for pdf_file in pdf_files:
        current_pdf = fitz.open(pdf_file)
        single_pdf.insert_pdf(current_pdf)
        current_pdf.close()

    single_pdf.save(output_file)
    single_pdf.close()

